# SSIS Aggregation - No group by in drill down

Tags: ssis, aggregate

I have an SQL table which I would like to aggregate in SSIS by a unique string level. Other columns I easily SUM, AVG, but the string Name column I wish to group by doesnt give me that option in the drill down. Only count option which is not what I need of course.
What could be the issue?
any one had this experience?
Ilana

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that you're selecting `GROUP BY` for all of the columns in an `Aggregate Transformation`, and it's trying to force you to aggregate something.

If you're really just trying to `GROUP BY` all of the columns, say to eliminate duplicates, you would get much better performance by using a `SELECT DISTINCT` in your data source.

The `Aggregate Transformation` is a fully blocking transformation, which is to say it needs to pull the entire data set into memory, perform the `SELECT DISTINCT` in memory, and then allow the refined data set to pass into the destination, resulting in two full copies of the data in memory. Often, the SSIS server is under-powered for this sort of workload.

By using a `SELECT DISTINCT` in your data source the heavy lifting falls on the database server, which is much more well equipped to handle that work. As a bonus, it will reduce the amount of data travelling over the network to the package, so you'll pick up speed in both operations.

Comment: Although it seems in the print screen I am doing a groupby to all, it isnt so. I was just trying to show other fields do get group by. this is the only field I want to group by and it doesnt allow me. Anyhow, If I do Select Distinct, do you mean to use it as an SQL expresion in SSIS?

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue, I solved it by using derived column to create a new column of type DT_WSTR instead of NTEXT, which apparantly isn't available for Group by.

I didn't find anything of use online, hope this helps others as well.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30181399)